# Close eye icon and " App content hidden" text with white screen in recent apps list in Android device in payment apps

Tags: android, android-studio, payment, mobile-application

Does anybody knows what exactly a functionality is in recent apps, means I have seen in Android 13 that when any of the payment apps is in recent app screen then one blank screen is there along with eye close icon and a text showing "App content hidden", irrespective of the app lock means it is locked or not.

If anybody knows what exactly it is in Android, then please let me know.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVCqm.jpg)

Comment: Apps can chose to hide their content when you are not in the app. Anyway you should have asked this on the android website instead: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/255731/44325